# Dynamic programming: find possible sums of given digits to reach given sum

Tags: dynamic-programming

Maybe anyone has idea how to solve this problem using dynamic programming: I have a natural number. Let’s name it n. Then, have digits: 1, 3, 4. I have to find all possible sums (with repetitives) of n using digits above. For example.

```
n=3. Then solution:
1+1+1=3
3=3
```

I know how to solve this problem using recursion or loops, but I really have no idea how to solve it with dynamic programming. And how to write relation for subproblems.

Comment: [So] might be helpful too

Comment: @Henry I'm sorry, I've corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: condition on the first element in the sum.